# Storing elements of a string on a Linked List

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm having a small issue here with my linked list.
I built a linked list with strings and it worked perfectly.
Now since i'm using strtok() to separate the string I need help on storing the struct separately but keeping them connected.
Hope i explained it well

for now here's what i've got:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


 typedef struct dict_word *word;
 typedef struct node *Node;
 typedef struct double_linked_list *DLL;




 struct dict_word
 {
char words[100];
int year[10];
char eng_synonyms[100];
char heb_synonyms[100];
 };


 struct node
 {
word data;
Node *next;
Node *previous;
 };


 struct double_linked_list
 {
Node *head;
Node *last;
 };


 char *split(char words[100])
 {
int i;
char *word=strtok(words, "_#_");
char *year=strtok(NULL, "_#_");;  // assigning NULL for previousely where it left off
char *definition=strtok(NULL,"_#_");
char *synonyms=strtok(NULL,"_#_");

i=atoi(year);

printf("%s\n", word);
printf("%i\n",i);
printf("%s\n", definition);
printf("%s\n", synonyms);
return 0;
 }
```

and this is my function to insert node by having only one string:

```
 void insert_beginning(char words[99])
 {
struct node *var, *temp;
var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //explination about the (node *)
strncpy(var->data, words,99);

if (head==NULL)
{
    head=var;
    head->previous=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;
    last=head;
}
else
{
    temp=var;
    temp->previous=NULL;
    temp->next=head;
    head->previous=temp;
    head=temp;
}
 }
```

Comment: As you have many string to store, suggest to create those many char* to your struct.. Need some explanation about your question though

Comment: I need to build a double linked list that stores strings like:
love_#_1986_#_affection_#_ADORE and basically i'll need to have a function that stores each word but keeps them connected. Like if I need to search for ADORE the output should be Found ADORE in the word love

Comment: did I explained it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit surprised to see plain C code used to handle such abstract data in 2014.

Nevertheless, I think you should separate the actual book data from the list.

`strtok` will modify your initial string (inserting '\0' at the end of each token). If you want to access the various bits `strtok` has split the string into, you must memorize all the pointers to the tokens (word, definition, etc).

So you should create a structure to hold all this together :

```
typedef struct {
    const char * words;
    int          year;
    const char * definition;
    const char * synonyms;
} dict_word;
```

Now to create a new record, you will have to make a copy of the various tokens, just like you did previously in your linked list insertion.

But this time the copy will occur sooner, using the `strdup` function.

```
dict_word * create_record (char * raw) // raw record string
{
    // allocate a new object
    dict_word record = (dict_word *) malloc (sizeof (record));
    assert (record != NULL);

    /*
     * sanity checks left out for concision,
     * but you should make sure your input is properly formatted
     */

    // populate the fields
    record->word       = strdup (strtok(raw , "_#_"));
    record->year       = atoi   (strtok(NULL, "_#_"));
    record->definition = strdup (strtok(NULL, "_#_"));
    record->synomyms   = strdup (strtok(NULL, "_#_")); 

    // done
    return record;  
}
```

You will need a cleanup function to free all the memory allocated during record creation:

```
void delete_record (record * r)
{
    // first free all strings
    free (r->word);
    free (r->definition);
    free (r->synomyms);

    // then free the object
    free (r);
}
```

Now for the list.

Instead of mixing up the code that handles the list with the one that cares about books, you can define the list as a more independent object:

```
typedef struct sNode {
    struct sNode * next;
    struct sNode * prev;
    void *         data; // this will point to the linked objects
} listNode;

typedef struct
{
    listNode *head;
    listNode *tail; // either first/last or head/tail, but keep it consistent :)
} List;
```

First you will need to initialize the list:

```
void List_init (List * l)
{
    l->head = l->tail = NULL;
}
```

Then you will want to add elements to it

```
void List_put (List * list, void * data)
{
    // allocate a node
    listNode * node = (listNode *) malloc (sizeof (node));
    assert (node != NULL);

    // store data reference
    node->data = data;

    // insert the node at the end of list
    node->prev = list->tail;
    node->next = NULL;
    list->tail = node;
    if (list->head == NULL) list->head = node;
}
```

Finally, to use all this:

```
// create the list
List book_list;
List_init (&book_list);

/* ... */

// create the records
char * raw_record;
while ((raw_record = read_from_database ()) != DONE_READING)
{
    List_put (book_list, create_record (raw_record));
}

/* ... */

// browse the records
listNode * node;
for (node = book_list->head; node != NULL; node = node->next)
{
    dict_word * record = (dict_node *) node->data;

    // do whatever you want with your record
}
```

All this being said and done, C is inadequate at best to handle this kind of high-level data.

You could write a ***very much*** more compact, reliable and efficient equivalent in a variety of more modern languages, starting with C++.

Now if you're just a student asked by an old geezer of a professor to do some dusty C homework and hoping to get it done for you by an old geezer of a StackOverflow contributor, well... it's your lucky day.

Comment: lol wow thank you so very much I appreciate it even though I'm a student but I realized that for just a homework better off learning how to do it I really really appreciate it. I'll have a look and understand it all again thank you

Comment: My pleasure. I was a student once too, but back then (in such a remote place as Paris, France) there was no such thing as the Internet :) Also all this code is off the top of my head, so don't expect it to compile right out of the box.